# using an external url in a razor href

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Using Web Pages in WebMatrix, I want to send a user to a google map but I can't use the external url without getting an error of:

"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)."

I set up a table of values and the address column would take the user to the google map.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in rowItems)
        {
            var addr = item.AddressDisplay;
            var url = "@http://maps.google.com/?q";
            //var addr = rawaddr.Replace(" ", "+");
            url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url + addr);

        <tr>
            <td class="tableCallAlighLeft">@item.EventDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
            <td class="tableCallAlighLeft">@item.EventType</td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft">@item.TimeStart.ToString("hh:mm tt")</td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft">@item.TimeEnd.ToString("hh:mm tt")</td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft">@item.VenueName</td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft"><a href="@url">@item.AddressDisplay</a></td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft">@item.CostMin.ToString("C")</td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft">@item.CostMax.ToString("C")</td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft">@item.Family</td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft">@item.MinAge</td>
            <td class="tableCellAlignLeft">@item.Adult</td>
        </tr>
        } 
</tbody>
```

How can I allow item.AddressDisplay to go to Google Maps?

Thanks!

Comment: you know about Google Maps, but not about Google Search? - https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22A+potentially+dangerous+Request.Path+value+was+detected%22

Comment: I am aware of Google Search but I was under the impression that Stackoverflow was a site where people happily gave assistance to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
<a href='@string.Format("http://maps.google.com?q={0}", addr)'>@item.AddressDisplay</a>
```